# Python return for to_bytes not as expected

Tags: python, integer, byte

(1112).to_bytes(8, 'big')

```
Return:
# b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04X'

Expected:
# b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x58'
```

If I convert back from

```
# b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04X'
```

then the result is still 1112. Is this just a print issue with encoding?

Answer (score 2):

This is normal behavior for `bytes` strings. Their printable representations show ASCII characters if possible, the hex values otherwise. As an example to show the expected value is still there:

```
>>> a = (1112).to_bytes(8, 'big')
>>> a
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04X'
>>> hex(a[7])
'0x58'
>>> chr(a[7])
'X'
```